# How can I include a tablename in a store procedure that truncates a table?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to fix this procedure that is supposed to truncate a table (parameter) if it exists.

I think my problem is the '' in OBJECT_ID('table_name')

How can I fix my error?

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[TruncateTable] @SchemaName varchar(256), @TableName varchar(256)
AS
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(2000)
SET @SQL='TRUNCATE TABLE ' + @SchemaName + '.' + @TableName;
if object_id (''''+@TableName+'''') is not null 
EXEC (@SQL);
```

Comment: What is the objective of this `Stored Procedure` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would, personally, use the `sys` objects and construct the dynamic query that way:

```sql
ALTER PROC dbo.TruncateTable @SchemaName sysname, --Correct data type for objects
                             @TableName sysname AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
    SELECT @SQL = N'TRUNCATE TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(s.[name]) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(t.[name]) + N';'
    FROM sys.schemas s
         JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
    WHERE s.[name] = @SchemaName
      AND t.[name] = @TableName;

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
END;
```

Then if the object doesn't exist, on the relevant schema, the value of `@SQL` will be `NULL` and no dynamic SQL will be run.

Comment: You're welcome, @ChristianHoffmann . If this did answer the question, please do mark it as a the solution, so that future readers know it was useful.